# SQLAlchemy: filtering for string/number queries result in "?" in SQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with a basic join query in SQLAlchemy.

SQLAlchemy Query

```
with Session.begin() as session:
    fs = session.query(Plan.CoveragePlanId, Plan.ClientId).\
        join(
            History, 
            and_(
                History.ClientCoveragePlanId == Plan.ClientCoveragePlanId, 
                History.RecordDeleted.contains('N')
            ),
            isouter = True
        ).\
            filter(
                and_(
                    Plan.CoveragePlanId == 17436,
                    Plan.RecordDeleted == 'N',
                    Plan.ClientId != 1092374
                )
            )
```

And here's the SQL output from the engine.

```
SELECT 
  [ClientCoveragePlans].[CoveragePlanId] AS [ClientCoveragePlans_CoveragePlanId], 
  [ClientCoveragePlans].[ClientId] AS [ClientCoveragePlans_ClientId] 
FROM 
  [ClientCoveragePlans] 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [ClientCoverageHistory] ON [ClientCoverageHistory].[ClientCoveragePlanId] = [ClientCoveragePlans].[ClientCoveragePlanId] 
  AND (
    [ClientCoverageHistory].[RecordDeleted] LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
  ) 
WHERE 
  [ClientCoveragePlans].[CoveragePlanId] = ? 
  AND [ClientCoveragePlans].[RecordDeleted] = ? 
  AND [ClientCoveragePlans].[ClientId] != ?
```

I've tried removing the quotes around numbers, same result. As you can see above, I tried `column == 'n'` and `column.containers('n')` with the same results. What stupid thing am I overlooking?

Comment: The '?' characters are placeholders for values (assuming your backend in sqlite).  SQLA is showing you the query _before_ the values are injected.  There should be another log line shortly afterwards that shows the values.

Comment: Is this query actually failing? What kind of SQL database are you actually connecting to? I  am reasonably sure SQLAlchemy is emitting a prepared statement, so your actual parameter values would be bound as and when you actually execute the query. If this is the case then for debugging purposes (and *only* debugging purposes) you can view the query with the parameters bound to it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#rendering-bound-parameters-inline

Comment: Thanks both of you! I am NOT using SQLite, I'm connecting to a remote SQL Server database and manually modelling the tables I need to use.

The query is not failing, though it's also not returning any rows when I am expecting it to. I tried compile() but it doesn't work (query object has no attribute compile), maybe it needs to be a select(). Not sure how to use those yet.

Answer (score 0):

@snakecharmerb and @PaddyAlton sent me down the right path. The '%' symbol does represent a variable pre-rendering.

You can also print the raw SQL of a SQL Server query using the method below:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mssql
from somewhere import Session

with Session.begin() as session:
    myquery = db.session.query(Model).all()
    print(myquery.statement.compile(
        session, 
        dialect=mssql.dialect(), 
        compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}
        )
    )
```

Thanks for the help!